# How to get the Google OpenID Identity URL in Ruby

Tags: ruby, openid

I'm trying to move my web application to the Google Chrome store, and I want to charge for premium features.  The problem is, to use the [Chrome Web Store License API](http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/check_for_payment.html) I need their Google OpenID identifier. I've read other similar questions, but none with code examples.

I found [this example](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_ruby.html), but it seems to be for a different purpose.

So my question is, how do I use the [Federated Login](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) in a Sinatra / Rack environment to get that one parameter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authenticate users with OpenID. The link has an example that shows how to use `Rack::OpenID`.

With Google, instead of requesting the openid_identifier from the user you would need to hardcode `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` as identifier (instead of `params["opened_identifier"]`) then run normal OpenID.